# 2048 Java Game: To move function

Tags: java

I recreated the 2048 game. I just have one problem. When the user enters the letter corresponding to the move it should move in that direction, print the game board and stop until the user enters a  letter again. I use switch statements to do this but when the user would enter for example, "R" the loop just keeps going. I mean the program prints the game board and it doesn't stop. How do I stop it?

```
boolean play = true;
while (play == true)
{
    boolean canMove = false;
    switch(answer)
    {
        case "U":
            canMove = moveUp(board,dimension);
            break;
        case "D":
            canMove = moveDown(board,dimension);
            break;
        case "R":
            canMove = moveRight(board,dimension);
            break;
        case "L":
            canMove = moveLeft(board,dimension);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            printBoard(board,dimension);
            answer = in.next();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you change `answer` after the board has been moved?

Comment: Where do you change the value of "play" variable? the methods moveLeft/move Down/moveUp, what they do?

Answer (score 2):

The statement `play` is left on `true`. When the user enters the character, the statement is still left to `true`. Since there are no other user input line, the program is stuck in a loop.

To solve this in my opinion, you should add a user input line of code after `while (play == true)` and in each case add `play = false;` before the `break;`.